# Namespaces when converting tool from windows 8 to windows 7

Tags: winapi, windows-8, windows-7, namespaces, directx

I am trying to convert the visual studio 3d starter kit to windows 7(For source and documentation: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Visual-Studio-3D-Starter-54ec8d19), because it is only made for windows 8 apps (ridiculous).

However I am stuck at using namespaces (I am not really familiar with windows sdk). The starter kit (VSD3DStarter.h) uses namespaces like Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader (and many others), but I just don't know which includes I need for these classes and namespaces (if they even exist).

Is there a way I can figure out which includes I need for these namespaces? Or if there are other ways to use these namespaces.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those namespaces are new for Windows 8 and only for non-desktop apps (so "Windows Store" or "Windows Phone" only). So there's no way to use them on Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks! Just needed to know if there are some option. So maybe using another tool is the best option?